# Playing while downloading game in the PS4

Tags: ps4, infamous-first-light

So, I was downloading Infamous: First Light on the PS4 and the total size it says "9.6gb" to my surprise at 6 and something I could start the game, but some "data app" has started downloading. My question is, is there a problem if I start the game like that? will I have performances troubles and stuff? I´ve been reading and this looks normal in some games, like The Last of us but I´m not sure if is more like "to test" the game or to play as normal.

Comment: No way man, that's just the beauty of the PS4 <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour is completely possible. According to the Features page of [playstation.com](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/explore/ps4/features/):

> **Play as You Download**
>
> Increase your play time with the ability to play games while they’re downloading titles. When a player purchases a game that is enabled with this feature, the PS4™ system downloads a portion of the game, so play can start, while the rest is downloaded in the background during actual gameplay.

When a certain part of the game is downloaded, you can play. You can only play a certain part of the game, as pointed out by Nitro.de. In case of DA:Inquisition you can only play until the Tutorial Boss. You are more likely to hit the limit when your download is slow.

Comment: You should add that it's still possible that the game will "stop" at a certain point if the download is too slow. E.g. Dragon Age Inquisition will stop after the "toturial boss" has been defeated if the game did not download completely at this point.

Comment: So apparantly inFAMOUS: First Light has this feature, but I cannot find any official source of this. However, that you can play as you download the remainder of the game is intended, so it shouldn't do any more harm then playing the game normally.

Comment: Here's a discussion about the play while download feature http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/691087-playstation-4/68096881 The interesting here is, that this is a PS4 feature which can be used by developers but is not a must-have

Comment: Perfect then. I was kinda scared that the game could have some problems or my saves will not work after the whole download was done. Thanks!

Comment: @Zarathustrax Nope, just play :). The only problem you can encounter, is that you hit the maximum playability,as pointed out by Nitro.de

Comment: I know that this is possible on some games on PC, like all the blizzard games and some other games through steam, in case someone is wondering.
Does xbox one also have this feature?

Comment: @Jubatus [Yes](http://www.polygon.com/2013/7/16/4527998/xbox-one-play-after-partial-download)